# jQuery .map into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, functional-programming

I don't know how I would .map into an array. I want to get all values of children but 2 and then put it into an array format.

Here's the code I'm attempting it with:

```
$("#schoolSupplies").submit(function() {
    var test = $(":input").not("#numOfSupplies, #submitBtn").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    })
    .get()
  .join( "\", \"" );

    console.log(test);
});
```

And this is the output: `Billy", "John`

I have been working on this for about an hour and I have no idea how.

Comment: Could you show example input and output, the desired output and what you are actually getting?

Comment: also provide html with it

Comment: Here's an output of what I get if I make more than just output 3", "1", "5", "   I want something like that but I don't want the first and last element to not have " and I want everything to be surrounded by [ ]. Why would you need HTML for it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get) returns an array - so just take out the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) call; otherwise `test` would be a string (since [that is what `.join()` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#return_value)).

```js
$("#schoolSupplies").submit(function() {
    var arrayOfValues = $(":input").not("#numOfSupplies, #submitBtn").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    })
    .get()
  //.join( "\", \"" )
    ;

    console.log('Array.isArray(arrayOfValues): ', Array.isArray(arrayOfValues)?'yes':'no', ' contents of arrayOfValues: ', arrayOfValues);
    return false; //for demonstration purposes, don't submit form normally
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="schoolSupplies">
  Supply Name: <input id="name" type="text" value="Tables" /><br />
  
  Student Name: <input id="studentName" type="text" value="Bobby"/><br />
  # of Supplies: <input id="numOfSupplies" type="number" value="3" /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" />
  </form>
```

Comment: I found `toArray()` also works... which one is 'better'? (or is there no such thing as "better" in javascript?)

Comment: It appears [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray) was added in version 1.4 while [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get) was added in version 1.0, which is likely why the documentation for [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map) suggests using it. “Better” is subjective - one could argue semantically `toArray` is better but `get` returns the same and is shorter to write. See also [this related GH issue](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/443).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$("#schoolSupplies").submit(function() {
    var test = $(":input").not("#numOfSupplies, #submitBtn").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    })
    .get()
  .join( "\", \"" );
    test = '["'+test+'"]';//note this is a string not a array
    console.log(test);
});
```